# How to strike through on single click & delete on double click a particular tag

Tags: javascript, runtime-error

I am trying my best to do this. Please help

when click 1st data the last data in the list is Strike through & same for delete
what I am basically trying is to strike through on single click & delete on double click the same data which is clicked

here is the code

```js
let addButton = document.getElementById('add');
let displayData = document.getElementById('display');
let data = document.getElementById('txt');

addButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  para = document.createElement('p');

  para.innerHTML = data.value;
  para.classList.add('pStyle');

  displayData.appendChild(para);
  data.value = '';
  para.addEventListener('click', () => {
    para.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
  });
  para.addEventListener('dblclick', () => {
    displayData.removeChild(para);
  });
  console.log(para);
});
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner" id="display">
    <h3>Todo List</h3>
    <input type="text" id="txt" />
    <button id="add">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner" id="display">
        <h3>Todo List</h3>
        <input type="text" id="txt" />
        <button id="add">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>

Comment: Problem is the use of undeclared `para` variable. Declare `para` before using it: [Demo](https://jsbin.com/weduhodewa/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Please add some description of the error/problem you are facing. So that one can get the idea of the error at first glance.